# Why does the object move when scaling on the Y axis?

Tags: transforms

I try to resize the object on the Y axis, but the object moves from where it is. There is no such problem with the X and Z axes.
What is the reason for this strange behavior?

X-Axis (S X):
[image]

Z-Axis (S Z):
[image]

Y-Axis (S Y):
[image]

Comment: It looks as if you may have the Transform pivot point set to 3D Cursor (middle of the top toolbar), but since all your images were taken while you were scaling, the toolbar isn't visible. Try setting it to Median Point and try again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The object's origin is at the world's center.

Go to menu *Object > Set origin > Origin to Geometry*